# Improving Duplicate Finder and For Loop Performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, duplicates

I have made a script that will find duplicates of a key in an array of objects. If duplicates are found a new key and value ("Duplicate": true) is added to the objects with the duplicate key values.

### Data Example

```
{
    "Id": "1",
    "NI Number": "NG111111A",
    "Full Name": "Test Test Tester",
    "Address Line 1": "My House",
    "Address Line 2": "My Road",
    "Address Line 3": "My Suburb",
    "City / Town": "My Town",
    "Country": "United Kingdom",
    "PostCode": "",
    "Creation Date": "24 December 2014"
},
{
    "Id": "2",
    "NI Number": "NM123405C",
    "Full Name": "A Dummy",
    "Address Line 1": "Dummy 1",
    "Address Line 2": "Dummy 2",
    "Address Line 3": "Dummy 3",
    "City / Town": "Dummy 4",
    "Country": "United Kingdom",
    "PostCode": "",
    "Creation Date": "09 February 2015"
}
```

### Script

```
for (let i = 0, len = cleanedData.length; i < len; i++) {

    let foundDuplicate = false;

    if (cleanedData[i]["Duplicate"] === "false" || cleanedData[i]["Duplicate"] === undefined) {

        for (let t = i + 1, len = cleanedData.length; t < len; t++) {

            if (cleanedData[i]["NI Number"] === cleanedData[t]["NI Number"]) {
                foundDuplicate = true;
                cleanedData[t]["Duplicate"] = true;
            }

        }

        if (foundDuplicate === true) {
            cleanedData[i]["Duplicate"] = true;
        } else {
             cleanedData[i]["Duplicate"] = false;
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to find duplicate "NI Numbers" in 33,000 records. The NI number can be repeated more than once. The script currently works as expected but takes over 70 seconds to run. I would like to reduce that to 35 seconds if possible.

I am new to JavaScript but from what I have read using a for loop with cached length is the fast way to iterate through an array. I have read that map, set could increase performance, but I am not sure how to implement them into my script.

Is there any way increase performance of my code?

Comment: You have some issues, e.g. `cleanedData[i]["Duplicate"] === "false"` will always be false since you set the value to a boolean, then strict compare with a string. Consider `if (!cleanedData[i].Duplicate) {...}`.

Comment: You can write it asynchronus, but you have to split it in two functions one would be callback, so every variable in object would be checked for duplicates in same time.

Comment: @RobG Thanks, well spotted.

Comment: Your script runs n^2 times. A simple solution is to create a lookup variable, loop over your data, check if `NI Number` exists in lookup variable; if it exists then mark current item as duplicate else add the key in lookup variable. This loops n times.

Comment: @SalmanA—the first duplicate must be marked as a duplicate too so the lookup would need to also store the index of the first instance of the value, e.g. `{"NG111111A":0,"NM123405C":1,...}`.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks for your advice. RobG implemented it and the code runs in a second!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any benchmarking tool so hopefully the following helps out.

You can reduce the number of tests, and do as few lookups as you can. Also, some of your tests are faulty as you assign booleans but test against strings. Hopefully the comments are sufficient.

```js
// Reduce test data to minimum required, increase sample size
var cleanedData = [
  {"Id": "1","NI Number": "NG111111A"},
  {"Id": "2","NI Number": "NM123405C"}, // Duplicate
  {"Id": "3","NI Number": "NM123405D"},
  {"Id": "4","NI Number": "NM123405E"}, // Duplicate
  {"Id": "5","NI Number": "NM123405C"}, // Duplicate
  {"Id": "4","NI Number": "NM123405E"}, // Duplicate
  {"Id": "4","NI Number": "NM123405F"}, 
  {"Id": "4","NI Number": "NM123405E"}  // Duplicate
 ];

// Use var for better compatibility unless you really need let
for (var i = 0, iLen = cleanedData.length; i < iLen; i++) {
   
  // Store ref to current object for performance
  var obj = cleanedData[i];

  // If doesn't have Duplicate property, add and set to false
  // Only test if not already marked as a duplicate
  if (!('Duplicate' in obj)) {
    obj.Duplicate = false;

    // Reuse iLen, don't need to get length of array again
    for (var t = i + 1; t < iLen; t++) {

      // Store ref to test obj for performance
      var tObj = cleanedData[t];

      // Simplify assignment to both objects if duplicate found
      if (obj['NI Number'] === tObj['NI Number']) {
        obj.Duplicate = true;
        tObj.Duplicate = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(cleanedData)
```

Please let me know if it helps performance. You can also use array methods like *forEach*, but I think *for* loops are at least as fast and much faster in some hosts.

Implementing an index as suggested by Salman A would go something like the following, it's concise (well, one line less than the first method) and likely quite fast as it only loops once, but it does do many more writes to *index*.

```js
var cleanedData = [
  {"Id": "1","NI Number": "NG111111A"},
  {"Id": "2","NI Number": "NM123405C"}, // Duplicate
  {"Id": "3","NI Number": "NM123405D"},
  {"Id": "4","NI Number": "NM123405E"}, // Duplicate
  {"Id": "5","NI Number": "NM123405C"}, // Duplicate
  {"Id": "4","NI Number": "NM123405E"}, // Duplicate
  {"Id": "4","NI Number": "NM123405F"}, 
  {"Id": "4","NI Number": "NM123405E"}  // Duplicate
 ];
 
// Store NI Number value and index first found
var index = {};

for (var i=0, iLen=cleanedData.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  var obj = cleanedData[i];
  var value = obj['NI Number'];

  // If obj doesn't have Duplicate property, add as false
  if (!('Duplicate' in obj)) obj.Duplicate = false;

  // If value is in index, mark duplicates
  if (value in index) {
    obj.Duplicate = true;
    cleanedData[index[value]].Duplicate = true;
    
   // Otherwise, add value to index
  } else {
    index[value] = i;
  }
}

console.log(cleanedData);
```

Comment: Your code has improved performance by nearly 20% which is great, thanks. It takes just over 50 seconds to complete now. I am running this using nodejs on my pc. Do you think we can make any other performance gains? P.s. I did try and upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Wow... It now takes 1 second to complete. That's my issue solved, thanks again!